# MacBook Pro External Monitors Change Numbers

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Every day I arrive at work with my 2016 Macbook Pro I plug in the 2 HDMI cords that go to my two external displays. Once in a while (sometimes multiple days in a row) the monitors will change their number. Display 2 on my right will now become display 3 and the one on my left will go from Display 3 to 2 and the desktops I had on the one will now be on the other.  I can't assign a program to a display because it eventually changes and I have to undo it so I just don't bother anymore.  I tested and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with what order I plug them in.  I can't seem to duplicate it on a whim. It just happens often enough to be annoying. Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: do you always plug them in in same order ? it will identify the first monitor as 2 as you plug it in

Comment: I tried plugging them in different orders and couldn't duplicate it. I also tried unplugging them in different orders and doing ever possible unplug and replug combo there is.  Didn't seem to affect a thing. They came on in the right spots with the right number regardless.

Comment: give it time to identify

Comment: I did.  Everything was up and ready to be used

Comment: so it worked or not

Comment: as you come in the office, first plug the monitor that you want as #2, go get coffee, then plug the next monitor

Comment: It was a good idea but I'm afraid it did not work.  I plugged in the one that I would like to be monitor 2 (currently its 3) then waited about 3 minutes after the screen was on and ready to use then plugged in the other but alas, they stayed in their current configuration.  Which wouldn't be bad except I know they'll randomly change again one of these days.  Just and FYI if this helps: the arrangement stays the same.  The right monitor knows its too the right of my macbook no matter what and same for the left.  the desktops and number designation is what changes

Comment: sorry, I was not clear, that will not work with Mac still on, it will remember, but to simulate going home turn it off, then on then plug in

Comment: suggestion: any possibility that the connection very reliable, but not 100% reliable, like a loose cable or bad cable?

Comment: Unlikely. The cables, monitors, and hdmi adapters are all pretty new. Like the oldest is September.   The adapters are from Apple and the monitors are an HP and Samsung. The cables came with the monitors.